# How do I show a selected area of source code, without copying the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, view

How do I show a selected area of source codes from a page? Not from the entire page. This example of what I am using now works, but it shows the source codes of the entire web page.

How do I do to show the source codes of a selected part of the page instead?

Is there a way to target this system I am using now, so that it shows a selected area of source codes? That is without the use of copying the code for a `<pre>` or `<textarea>`, because if that is the only way, then there is no more question on this.

**My JavaScrip:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewSourceButton/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script languade="JavaScript">
        $(function() {
            $("<pre />", {
                "html":   '&lt;!DOCTYPE html>\n&lt;html>\n' + 
                        $("html")
                            .html()
                            .replace(/[<>]/g, function(m) { return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]})
                            .replace(/((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi,'<a href="$1">$1</a>') + 
                        '\n&lt;/html>',
                "class": "prettyprint"
            }).appendTo("#source-code");

            prettyPrint();
        });
</script>

<script languade="JavaScript">
        var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script languade="JavaScript">
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-68528-29");
        pageTracker._initData();
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>
```

**My HTML:**

```
<a class="button" href="#source-code" id="view-source">Show the Source Code for this page</a>
<div id="source-code" align="left">
    <a href="#" id="x"><input type="button" alt="close" class="control-copytextarea" value=" Close Source Code Viewing " /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Which part?  Store the html as a string and parse it using an index and display from index a to b depending on which part to display.

Comment: You would need to first scrape the *entire* document as a string, then use a regex to work out a start point to display, and a secondary regex to work out an end point. Then simply output the characters between these two points: **`source.substr(start, length - end)`**.

Comment: Yes I could copy it, change it and show it separately using `<pre></pre>`, but my question is if there is a way to target this system I have that shows source codes so that it shows only a part of it. PS: I will now add the clarify the question now.

Comment: Aha okay. I will try that. We wrote at the same time and I did not see your second text till now. Thank you.